# Android Studio Button onClick listener in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, button

I'm a newbie and i tried to learn the navigation drawer.
I want to set a onClick listener on a button in Fragment but when i run the App, the button do nothing.

this is WeightFragment.java:
`

```
public class WeightFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentWeightBinding binding;
    private EditText edtNumber;
    private Button addBtn;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WeightViewModel weightViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeightViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentWeightBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight, container, false);
        addBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        edtNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
        String weight = String.valueOf(edtNumber.getText());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date\n'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),weight + currentDateAndTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final TextView textView = binding.txtDate;
        weightViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

I've tried with:

```
public class WeightFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

and implement the method but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are setting the `onClickListener` on a View that you throw away.

Here is the binding (pay attetion to the `root`):

```
binding = FragmentWeightBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
View root = binding.getRoot();
```

but you are setting the listener on a button that is in:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight, container, false);
addBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
addBtn.setOnClickListener(...);
```

and at the end you `return root;`

The view that has the onClick listener is there, you create it but in the end it's thrown away.

Just replace `view` with `binding` and it will work.

```
public View onCreateView(
    @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    WeightViewModel weightViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeightViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentWeightBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    addBtn = binding.addBtn;
    edtNumber = binding.edtNumber;
    String weight = String.valueOf(edtNumber.getText());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date\n'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),weight + currentDateAndTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    final TextView textView = binding.txtDate;
    weightViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
    return root;
}
```